# Conditionals inside a for-loop

Tags: c#, loops

I'm trying to figure out why my code doesn't run. Can anybody give me some inputs on how to solve this short code?

```
    int num1, num2;
    num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if (num1 == 56)
            Console.WriteLine(Add(i, num1));
            num2--;
        else num1 = 56;
    }
}

static int Add(int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

Comment: What is the error?  What is your input, expected output and actual output?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? What is the meaning of 56?

Comment: you are missing curly braces, you don't initialize num1, no idea what the code is trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not compile because of a couple of things. The main part is the `if/else` construct.

In C# there is a shortcut syntax for writing an if condition. If you have only 1 line of code after the if-statement then you can ommit the curly braces which define the scope. This compiles nicely:

```
    if (num1 == 56)
        Console.WriteLine(Add(i, num1));
    else num1 = 56;
```

but if you insert more lines of code between the `if` and `else` the compiler does not know anymore where the `else` belongs to. And it tells you so with an error message:

> **} expected**

So in this case you need to define the scope of the if-block.

```
if (num1 == 56)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Add(i, num1));
    num2--;
    // all the rest of the code that you wish to be executed
}
else num1 = 56;
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else) says the following:

> Both the then-statement and the else-statement can consist of a single statement or multiple statements that are enclosed in braces ({}). For a single statement, the braces are optional but recommended.

The second thing that the compiler will complain about is that:

> use of unassigned local variable 'num1'

in the if condition `if (num1 == 56)`. You need to give this variable an initial value:

```
int num1 = 0, num2;
```

and please close the last parentheses in the `Add` method. Now your code should compile and run

Answer (score 2):

Define a scope for `if/else` statement.

```
    int num1, num2;
    num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if (num1 == 56)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Add(i, num1));
            num2--;
        }
        else num1 = 56;
    }
```

You are executing just the `Console.WriteLine` after the `if`. If you do not define a scope using `{` and `}` it will accepct a single statement after `if` or `else`.